# remove item from a map of string

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a map of string `Map<String, String> data = {};` and I added user input items and store it in the map. but when I try to remove the item the key/id changes and the value becomes null.

this is what I have when I added the items and remove them after.

```
//called on onChanged
if (data.containsKey('$index') && value != null) {
   data['$index'] = value!;
}

//called on remove
data.remove('$index');
data.removeWhere((key, value) => key == "");

//added result
print(${json.encode(data)});
```

before remove called=> `{"0":"Manager","1":"Service","2":"Sales","3":"Reception"}`,

after remove called=> `{"0":"Manager","1":"Service","3":"Reception","4":""}`

what should be => `{"0":"Manager","1":"Service","2":"Sales"}`

so what is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.remove(key)` to remove all `key` along with its value.

```dart
  final data = {
    "0": "Manager",
    "1": "Service",
    "2": "Sales",
    "3": "Reception"
  };
  data.remove("3");
  print(data); //{0: Manager, 1: Service, 2: Sales}
});
```

More about [/Map/remove](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-core/Map/remove.html)

Comment: yeah but still it has an empty value, like `{"0":"Manager","1":"Reception","2":"Sales"}` when I remove this it returns `{"0":"Manager","2":"Sales","3":""}`

Comment: You must be writing something wrong because it returns the correct map as @Yeasin Sheikh described

Comment: @mobix I suspect the issue is coming from else where. it would be easier if you include sample data on test/main dart file and how you've proceed the remove operation. if you can follow my post and it will work.